# I can't deploy react app using npm run deploy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, deployment

I need advice to debug deployment of React site from Github to Netlify.

I use the code below for deployment: npm run deploy

This is Error on terminal:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! v1.0.0@0.1.0 deploy: `inhyechoi -d build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the v1.0.0@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

What I have tried so far:

-uninstall npm
-reinstall npm with latest update
-remove node modules
-install node modules
-npm cache clear
-npm ci

This is the github repo: https://github.com/inhyechoi/inhyechoi-portfolio/

Complete log:

```
v1.0.0@0.1.0 deploy /Users/inhyechoi/Desktop/InhyeChoi/react/portfolio/inhyechoi-portfolio-react
inhyechoi -d build 
sh: inhyechoi: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! v1.0.0@0.1.0 deploy: `inhyechoi -d build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the v1.0.0@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `deploy` command in your package.json is `"deploy": "inhyechoi -d build -b master"`

The error is saying `inhyechoi` is not a command, which is correct that is only the name of your project, not a program that can be called in terminal.

To build a react app run `npm run build` or `npm run-script build`.
To deploy with netlify I believe you just run `netlify` deploy" so try changing your package.json's `deploy` command to `"deploy" : "netlify deploy"`

If you want to build and deploy you may have to change it to `"deploy": "npm run build; netlify deploy"`